# Doesnt execute my MySql Query

Tags: c#, mysql

i have a little problem with my C# code(im normally a c++ dev so i just know most of the basics of c#)

I wanted to write a class to execute a SQL query using that programm but atm it does nothing and i don´t get any error from it.

The MySqlConnectionHandler Class which i wrote:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WS_Studio_tool
{
    class MySqlConnectionHandler
    {
        private MySqlConnection connection;
        private string ConnectionString;

        public MySqlConnectionHandler()
        {
            try
            {
                ConnectionString = "SERVER=localhost;" +
                                   "DATABASE=ws_creator_beta;" +
                                   "UID=root;" +
                                   "PASSWORD=AF362GL!";
                connection = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString);
            }
            catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "MySql Fehler!");
            }
        }
        public bool InsertRow(string SQL_Query)
        {
            try
            {
                 MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
                 command.CommandText = SQL_Query;
            }
            catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "MySql Fehler!");
            }
            return true;
        }


    }
}
```

My Function Call(I played a lot with it so it could contain things that are not necessary):

```
    string newquery = QueryTextBox1.ToString();
    MySqlConnectionHandler SqlHandler = new MySqlConnectionHandler();
    SqlHandler.InsertRow(newquery);
```

And my MySql Query:

```
INSERT INTO user_data (username,passwd) VALUES ('asdf', 'asdf');
```

It would be very nice if somebody could take a quick look at it, maybe you are able to find the error..

Comment: Do you get any exception or error message?

Comment: Nope, runs without errors, as i said - it just doesnt executes my sql

Comment: you dint put command.executenonquery() inside the InsertRow() method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not [telling the command to execute](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-ref-mysqlclient-mysqlcommandmembers.html#connector-net-ref-mysqlclient-mysqlcommand-executenonquery): also, you need to explicitly [open the connection before using it](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples-mysqlconnection.html#connector-net-examples-mysqlconnection-open), so add these lines to InsertRow:

```
connection.Open();
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I'd also suggest disposing of the connection once you're done with it - either by implementing `IDisposable` on the `MySqlConnectionHandler` class, or - easier - just create a connection within a `using` block when executing the query:

```
using (var connection = new new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
    { 
         command.CommandText = SQL_Query;
         connection.Open();
         command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: Now i get a runtime error that says: System.InvalidOperationException

Comment: Do you get the error when executing the query? Is there an inner exception with any details?

Comment: you are getting the excpetion because you are using command before linking the connection with command. @user2287114

Comment: There is still no Error with the SQL Query, just the Exception i posted before - buts in the right scope.

Comment: You also need to explicitly open the connection see edited answer.

Comment: @Saurabh the command is created from the connection so it's automatically associated - the trouble is the connection isn't open..

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, i think i can make the rest on my own.

Answer (score 0):

You did not call command.Execute, so your SQL never gets executed.